# Reaching files from a file server created with Raspberry and Samba

Tags: server, samba, file-sharing, raspberrypi

I'm trying to create a file server with my RaspberryPi to deploy all over the private network. It should allow the hard drive connected to be accessible when wired to the Raspberry. I therefore installed Samba and began to modify the settings.

On the Raspberry' side
, I then added a Sharing: by adding at the end of `sudo nano /etc/samba/smb.conf`

```
[Shares]
comment = Shares Folder
path = /media/Music/Shared
valid users = @users
force group = users
create mask = 0660
directory mask = 0771
read only = no
```

then, in order to add a user having the sharing access rights, I did

```
sudo useradd admin -m -G users

sudo useradd Gilleseve -m -G users


sudo useradd antoine -m -G users

sudo passwd Gilleseve
```

and gave ****

```
sudo passwd antoine
```

and gave ****** then restarted restarted samba

Yet, when, on my desktop now, I went there

[image: Shares]

I never was able to connect

[image: window pop up to access shares]

And this even after downloading samba on the desktop!

**Therefore, what did I missed? How to access the files I shared with my Raspberry?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you've missed the step of making samba users, which are different to your normal system users. They can be created with the same names and passwords though.

Try the following command for each username:

```
sudo smbpasswd -a <username>
```

You'll be prompted for the password twice, like with normal system users.
After you've completed this step, restart samba, and you should be able to access your shares.

Comment: Thank you, It works for one repository but not for the second one because of a "Failed to mount Windows share" error. I am thinking about asking a new question but I don't know if it is serious enough to ask.

Comment: Maybe check what the permission are on the mount point for the disk. Not sure that will solve it, but it's a place to start!